# Do .deb installed apps get updates?

Tags: updates, deb

So this might be very silly question for users, but I am quite new to Ubuntu and want to know this. Do `.deb` installed apps get updates?

For example: I have Opera installed with using `.deb` will it get updates like software that are installed using PPA?

I would gladly accept your answers if you will explain this as well:

[image]

As you can see `.deb` installed Skype added it's self to software source so will it or will it not get updates?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer depends on the situation.

If your installed .deb file has repository enabled or get enabled while installing, installed .deb packages will be updated. ***But, if your installed .deb file has no online repository, from which it can get updates, that package won't be updated***. The reason is clear, the package manager doesn't know anyway to update the package, because it doesn't know any online repository providing this same package.

If you have synaptic package manager installed, You can see those packages who do not have any repository enabled, or installed with .deb files without enabling a repository. Open synaptic package manager, Click *status* section and see under *Installed (local or obsolete)* section.

[image: synaptic obsolete packages]

Google-chrome and dropbox enable a repository while installing from .deb files, so you will get update for these packages.

**Note:** The same rule is true for packages which you installed via apt-get but later disabled the repository and no other repository provide those packages. In that case, you won't receive updates for these too.

Comment: From @Levan's screenshot, it seems that the opera `.deb` *did* enable its own repository. So yes, it *will* automatically upgrade.

Answer (score 8):

Some `deb`-files installs the package source too, so you can get updates.

**For example**, if you [download the Dropbox Ubuntu Debian file](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) and install it, you get `dropbox.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Then you can see, that the source is activated with `cat dropbox.list`, because there is no `#` in front of the line.:

```
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: Google Chrome does that too. That depends solely on the app you are installing to add its repo source into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`